# Popularity of path hooks (PEP 302 custom import)

Tags: python, path

My project has the ability to run python functions remotely.  Doing so requires transmitting modules a given function utilizes.  Determining what to send is conducted via a modified modulefinder.

As I modify the modulefinder to support arbitrary path_hooks, I've started to get the impression that  path_hooks are not all that popular.  Quick google codesearching seems to only show the ZipImporter using them.  I've noticed a minor project using it (and even then, its loader doesn't support the PEP 302 extension of get_code, which is needed by the modified modulefinder).

Has anyone come across or created projects that use custom path_hooks to access source code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I've coded some path hooks (for one of the obvious purposes: access modules living in other forms of storage besides the filesystem and zipfiles), but never on an open-source project (and actually never needed to support modulefinder in them). What difficulties are you encountering? While I can't share my original code I think I can share the know-how developed with it (though offhand I can't recall any special difficulties -- it has been a while). As for "popular", I guess they will be in direct proportion to the need to site modules "elsewhere" (e.g. in some form of DB), though of course general "usermode file systems" built e.g. using [fuse](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/) , [macfuse](http://code.google.com/p/macfuse/) and [dokan](http://dokan-dev.net/en/about/) may also allow this (and offer other advantages in terms of generality -- not sure how performance compares).

Comment: The main issue with supporting arbitrary path_hooks is being able to A) read the source code of a module without importing it and B) tracking changes.
A is solved if the get_code extension is implemented by the PEP 302 loader.  I suspect custom path hooks don't do this.
For B, I currently do timestamps (as python).  ZipImporter possesses the archive property.  To support arbitrary code, checksums would need to be taken of the code; and, if custom hooks are rarely ever used, the tracking system is not worth developing.

Comment: And thanks for the answer.  Your response and the lack of any others (or votes) conforms my hunch that they are very rare.